# Node Upload file to S3 error InvalidArgument: null

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I have this error with aws-sdk library and I didn't found the reason.

I have tried any possibilities for many days but without success and no clue of what's happen
It's a Status code 400 but I have checked for many examples in web and everything is fine to me.

Here is the code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'nyc3' });

var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var fs = require('fs');

// Create an S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  secretAccessKey: '*****',
  accessKeyId: '*****',
  endpoint: 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
  region: 'nyc3'
});

AWS.config.region = 'nyc3';

const fileName = 'hello_world.txt';

// Create a bucket and upload something into it
var bucketName = 'my-bucket';
var keyName = fileName;

fs.readFile(fileName, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  var params = {
    ACL: 'private',
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: keyName,
    Body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2),
    ContentLength: data.length
  };
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else
      console.log(
        'Successfully uploaded data to ' + bucketName + '/' + keyName
      );
  });

  // s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
  //   if (s3Err) console.log(s3Err);
  //   else console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`);
  // });
});
```

You can see that I have tried with the putObject and upload methods and have the same error in both of them

```
{ InvalidArgument: null
    at Request.extractError (/home/antonio/desenvolvimento/projetos/aws-nodejs-sample/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:816:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/antonio/desenvolvimento/projetos/aws-nodejs-sample/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/home/antonio/desenvolvimento/projetos/aws-nodejs-sample/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/antonio/desenvolvimento/projetos/aws-nodejs-sample/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/antonio/desenvolvimento/projetos/aws-nodejs-sample/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/antonio/desenvolvimento/projetos/aws-nodejs-sample/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/antonio/desenvolvimento/projetos/aws-nodejs-sample/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/antonio/desenvolvimento/projetos/aws-nodejs-sample/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/antonio/desenvolvimento/projetos/aws-nodejs-sample/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/antonio/desenvolvimento/projetos/aws-nodejs-sample/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
  message: null,
  code: 'InvalidArgument',
  region: null,
  time: 2020-02-28T03:20:24.289Z,
  requestId: 'tx00000000000016f648fab-005e5886f8-3359f-nyc3b',
  extendedRequestId: undefined,
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 38.29641987933954 }
```

I don't have any more idea of what I can do to fix this.
Any one can help?

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(data)` before submitting the S3 `putObject` call?

Comment: Hi @TheLebDev here the output <Buffer 74 65 73 74 65 0a>

Comment: So the data you're trying to upload is `<Buffer 74 65 73 74 65 0a>`?

Comment: Yes this is what i want to upload.

Comment: I would recommend first of all logging each and every single parameter being sent to the putObject, obviously, something is being interpreted as `null` and is crashing your call.

Comment: Yes, I already read the aws documentation to see something like that but wit no success.
With this log I believe that I have some problem with the location but I didn't find any other way to fill this information.